# Open a file explorer window from the terminal in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin-file-manager

Similar to macOS's `open .` command, and Windows 10's `explorer.exe .` command, I would like to be able to open Kubuntu's built in file-explorer from the terminal.

It looks like *Dolphin* is Kubuntu 20.04s file manager of choice. By running `dolphin .` I can open the file browser at the present working directory of my terminal, but the process stays open until I either close the file browser window, or cancel the process in the terminal (with `ctrl` + `c`).

Is there a way to open the pwd in the file browser in a single process that doesn't hang? I don't mind if the call is particularly long, since I'll likely create an alias for `open`, or something like that. Sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open it into the background with this:

`dolphin . &`

if you want it to completely detach and not send messages to the terminal then:

`nohup dolphin . 2>&1 > /dev/null &`

explaining this command by parts:

```
nohup -- don't kill this process if the terminal is closed.

dolphin -- the file browser

. -- the current directory

2>&1 -- redirect stderr to stdout

> /dev/null -- redirect stdout to the bitbucket
```